# Finding polynomial to the power of 2020

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, characteristic-polynomial, cayley-hamilton

I am trying to solve a homework problem, but I am stuck at a point where I don't know what am I suppose to do next.

We're given a $3 \times 3$ matrix

$$A =
\begin{pmatrix}1& 2& 2\\
2& 1& 2\\
2& 2& 1\end{pmatrix}$$

And we have to find a polynomial $p(x)$ such that deg($p(x)$) = 2020, and $p(A) = 0$ (as 0 matrix 3x3)

What I did was finding the characteristic polynomial which is $p(x) = (x-5)(x+1)^2$

And I know that if I use Cayley Hamilton I can place A in the characteristic polynomial and get the zero matrix. but what is that part with the degree 2020, I don't understand how do I do that or what do I rely on?

This might seem easy but I really can't see it. any help is appreciated :)

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need to do is multiply $(X-5)(X+1)^2$ by any polynomial of degree $2017$.

Comment: Thank you very much, any any polynomial would work?
And could you please explain a little why does this work ?

Comment: Yes: if $g(A)=O$ then $g(A)h(A)=O$.

Comment: Oh, I totally did not see that. Thank you again :)